# windows store app Listview Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, windows-8

I have a class with data:

```
public class routedata : INotifyPropertyChanged

{

    private List<double> distances;
    public List<double> Distances
    {
        get { return this.distances; }
        set
        {
            if (this.distances != value)
            {
                this.distances = value;
                this.onPropertyChanged("Distances");
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> instructions;
    public List<string> Instructions
    {
        get { return this.instructions; }
        set
        {
            if (this.instructions != value)
            {
                this.instructions = value;
                this.onPropertyChanged("Instructions");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void onPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }        
}
```

I'm trying to bind it to a listview like this:

```
     <GridView Name="routeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" Margin="1025,318,0,0" Grid.Row="1"      
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" >
            <ListView Name="routeList" Height="300" Width="330" ItemsSource="{Binding routeData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Instructions}"
                                                      TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Distances}"
                                                      Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="km"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </GridView>
```

I have in my c# code behind: routeList.datacontext = this;

but it is still not binding, only one empty row is populated in the listview. I have checked the data and it is all present. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: you have a single instance of routedata?  or a list of routedata elements?  Your GridView ItemsSource implies the latter.  ItemSource should be set to a collection, and then in your template you assign UI elements to individual members of the class in that collection.  You seem to have an inverted scenario.

Comment: I see. I have a single instance of route data. Should I just place the listview inside a grid? I tried this before and it still did not work. Thank you for response.

Comment: your route element is a single object and you have two different collections in it, but you're trying to pull both collections into a single grid, item by item.  What would happen if the Instructions and Distances  lists were different sizes?  see @FilipSkakun answer below; you're data model is what needs a bit of modification and then the bindings will flow naturally.

Comment: I can guarantee that instructions and distances will always be the same. I got this working with an alternative method before but that was wasn't registering onselectionchanged handler properly. But am trying to implement the proper method atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView takes a single collection as ItemsSource, so if you want to display multiple TextBlocks for each item - you need a collection of objects with multiple text properties to bind to your DataTemplate. In your case a routeData is not a collection. Instead you need to define your item view model, e.g.

```
public class RoutePoint
{
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public string Instruction { get; set; }
}
```

then you would bind your ListView.ItemSource to a List and in your DataTemplate bind it like that:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Instruction}"/>
```

You don't need to use an ObservableCollection if your collection never changes after you bind it to the ListView for the first time (SelectedItem doesn't constitute a change).

Comment: Okay, i made the class like you said. I put it in an observable collection. I confirm the collection is populated with members and data. I set the datacontext of listview to the collection (i also tried setting it to "this"). And i set item source of listview to the collection. Still no go. Only thing i change in my data template was the name Instruction and Distance. It is still within a grid view. Stubborn thing is going to kill me.

Comment: What is your DataContext? Have you tried simply assigning the collection to ItemsSource in code behind? Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If your view is called `routeView`, shouldn't your `DataContext` be set to a new instance of `routedata`? Also, I suggest you use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for your bindable collections rather than `List<T>`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions (observable collection and fiddling with datacontext) but it is still not displaying anything. Only a single row in the list view.